# mysql_query: Unknown error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add new filed in my datbase!
but i'm getting error in the mysql_query part!

he is the code

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass','data');
if(!$link)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$sql = "INSERT INTO content(`id`, `writer`, `title`, `subject`) VALUES(NULL,'11','22','33')";
if (!mysql_query($link,$sql))
  {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When i run this page i get

```
Invalid query:
```

and An Empty reason

any ideas?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's an antiquated interface that's dangerous when used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. [Learning PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or another supported interface will provide a number of benefits such as [easier SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and future support by PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You have your parameters to [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) backwards.

It should be `mysql_query($sql, $link)`.

P.S. You don't even need to pass `$link`.  You can just do `mysql_query($sql)`.  PHP will use the last link opened via `mysql_connect`.

Answer (score 1):

Whats your table definiton? I think "id" is your primary key (PK). A PK must not be NULL.

If it's auto_increment just leave the coloum away and write

```
"INSERT INTO content(`writer`, `title`, `subject`) VALUES('11','22','33')";
```

Comment: That's what my answer was going to be.  You beat me to it.

Comment: If you set a `PK` to `NULL`, it automatically sets it to the next `AUTO_INCREMENT` value.